# Как сделать атрибут title для колонки таблицы?

Tags: html, css

Требуется в таблице (размер может быть от 2 строк, до N) прописать атрибут title в одной или нескольких колонках. Для колонки для всех td в ней описание будет одинаковое.

Как правильно реализовать? в каждом поле вручную прописать как то не рационально.

Использовать для этого JS и событие наведения мышки на элемент, в котором прописывать этот атрибут?

Или может какие то другие способы есть?

```
<table id="table">
      <tr>
        <td title="Первая колонка"></td>
        <td title="Вторая колонка"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td title="Первая колонка"></td>
        <td title="Вторая колонка"></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Если не используете серверную часть или сборщик + шаблонизатор, то только js (но лучше вручную)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если понял вас правильно, то можно так задать `title`, а потом поменять.

```js
var td = document.querySelectorAll('td');
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Initializes title
td.forEach(function (el, i) { 
  el.title = 'Some Text No. ' + (i + 1);
  console.log(el.title);
});
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Меняет на Event Mouse Over
td.forEach(function (el, i) { 
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) { 
    e.target.title = 'Changed for No. ' + (i + 1); 
  })
})
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td title="Первая колонка">1.Test</td>
    <td title="Вторая колонка">2.Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td title="Первая колонка">3.Test</td>
    <td title="Вторая колонка">4.Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```